# Adding Title Overlay to Video.js player

Tags: video.js

I am new to Video.js, but like what I see so far.  One thing I have not seen: How to add a title to the top of the player, which will disappear on play, and reappear on pause.

I can see how to tie an action to these events, and I have read about adding elements to the player.  For instance (this example is only halfway done):

```js
var myContainer = videoObj.addChild('button');
myContainer.addClass("myContainer");
```

which I got from: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api/vjs.Component.md

that snippet adds this code:

```html
<div class="vjs-control  myContainer" role="button" aria-live="polite" tabindex="0" style="display: block;">
<div class="vjs-control-content">
<span class="vjs-control-text">Need Text</span>
</div>
</div>
```

But what I want is a simple DIV that will have a title, with code like this:

```html
<div class="myOverlay">
<h2>Title of Video</h2>
</div>
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree here?  Is there a better way to get what I want done?

Thanks in advance,
Bill

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried this videojs plugin?

https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-overlay

You can choose to show the overlay on certain events like start, playing or end of the video.

```
player = videojs('/path/to/video', options, function() {});
overlay_content = '<div class="myOverlay"><h2>Title of Video</h2></div>';
player.overlay({
  overlays: [{
    start: 'loadstart',
    content: overlay_content,
    end: 'playing',
    align: 'top'
  }, {
    start: 'pause',
    content: overlay_content,
    end: 'playing',
    align: 'top'
  }]
});
```